# AVUser, AVFile reports error

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class SignUpVC: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTxt: UITextField!
...
@IBOutlet weak var cancelBtn: UIButton!

@IBAction func signUpBtn_clicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let user = AVUser()
    user.username = usernameTxt.text?.lowercased()
    user.email = emailTxt.text?.lowercased()
    user.password = passwordTxt.text
    user["fullname"] = fullnameTxt.text?.lowercased()
    user["bio"] = bioTxt.text
    user["web"] = webTxt.text?.lowercased()
    user["gender"] = ""


    user.signUpInBackground{ (success: Bool, error:Error?) in
        if success{
            print("Signup OK")
        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

I am trying to write an app just like Instagram. I wanna send the signup information to leancloud account. Why it always report error in the following line:

```
let user = AVUser()
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you show the error you're getting and the relevant code for `AVUser`?

Comment: The error said "use of undeclared identifier AVUser",

Comment: The relevant code for AVUser are all above. Actually I wrote these code follow a book, the book didn't tell me anything about AVUser, it is quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, just update the xcode and reinstall the pods in the terminal.